# Separate display name for CV and SO profiles

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, display-names, privacy

I noticed my CV is automatically pre-filled with my profile *Display name*.

[image] [image]

Can I prevent such behavior of SO? 
I want my real name to be displayed in my CV and my nickname is to be displayed on all SO sites. Is it possible without affecting my privacy and putting real name everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click the edit button for that area of your developer story, you'll see that there are actually two different names to enter there: one that users of the site see when viewing your story (assuming it's public to them) and one that employers will see when you apply or find you in a talent search. Your display name is always coupled with the on-site display name, but it also only ever gets used on your main Stack Overflow profile anyways. The Full Name will only ever be shown to potential employers.

Comment: However, under the Full Name we see *How you appear to employers* **and** *other users when you share your Developer Story*, which contradicts your words. I understand this following way: both users and employers will see my full name

Comment: @Suncatcher "other users" in this context means anyone who is registered to use the Talent side of our Jobs platform, which is mostly just employers. Your full name is simply not accessible from the base Stack Overflow side.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarification.